# Attaching namespaces to mdapi object before deploying to a sandbox org?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, sandbox, namespace, mdapi

I am currently deploying my Salesforce code to a qa sandbox environment with the mdapi (`sfdx force:source:convert` -> `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`). However, we need the object and pages and etc when deployed to have a certain namespace. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata will have a namespace in a small number of circumstances.

1. It is installed as part of a managed package.
2. It is present in a namespaced scratch org, and hence has the namespace of that org.
3. (Slightly different) It is present in a packaging org and will have the namespace applied when uploaded, but doesn't present in the org with a namespace.

Metadata in a QA sandbox can have a namespace only if it is installed as part of the managed package that owns that namespace.

Under no circumstances can you create metadata in a namespace you do not control, i.e., own the corresponding packaging org.

Comment: Thanks for the response-- is it possible to install metadata into my sandbox as part of a managed package? hopefully solely through command line commands.

Comment: Sure. [`sfdx force:package:install`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm). Of course, you have to do the managed package release first, and you generally won't want to install a beta managed package because betas cannot be upgraded.